# What's the cause Undefined property: stdClass?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I don't know what this error cause. I didn't change anything in my codes. But when I go to my search view. It always returns me the undefined property error. This error cause when I tried to **foreach** all my columns in my table data. I already solve this error not once. Because it cannot find the `$id` of selected options. But this time I can't fix it.

Error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\document\show.blade.php)

**View**

show.blade.php - This view will list all the values in my tables.

```
@section ('content')

<div class = "col-md-12">

    <table class = "table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Date Received</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach ($documentLists as $list)
                <tr class = "info">
                    <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ strip_tags(substr($list->content, 0, 50)) }} {{  strlen($list->content) > 50 ? "..." : '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $list->category_type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($list->dateReceived)) }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href = "{{ route ('document.read', $list->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info">Read</button></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>

@endsection
```

read.blade.php - This where it will redirect to the current view that selected.

```
<!--DOCUMENT CONTROLLER-->
<div class = "col-md-6">

<form class = "vertical">

    <div class = "form-group">

        <textarea id = "content">{{ $documentLists->content }}</textarea>

    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">

        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Approve</button>

    </div>

</form>

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
//SHOW
public function showDocuments()
{

    $documentLists = DB::table('document_user')->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'document_user.dateReceived')
        //Table name     //PK                  //FK
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'document_user.sender_id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'document_user.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->where('sender_id', '!=', Auth::id())
        ->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

    //VIEW
    return view ('document.show')->with('documentLists', $documentLists);
}

//READ
public function readDocuments($id)
{
    //Find the document in the database and save as var.
    $documentLists = Document::find($id);

    return view ('document.read')->with('documentLists', $documentLists);
}
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/show',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@showDocuments',
    'as' => 'document.show',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
]);

Route::get('/receive/documents/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readDocuments',
    'as' => 'document.read',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In below you are not selecting id

```
$documentLists = DB::table('document_user')->select('documents.title', 'documents.
```

but calling in your blade `{{ route ('document.read', $list->id) }}`

Comment: Didn't notice that I'm selecting the `document_user.id` instead of `document.id` my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
$documentLists = DB::table('document_user')->select('documents.id','documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'document_user.dateReceived');
```

You need to select the column documents.id.But you have missed it